# Applying Pattern matching for Instanceof in the Stream

Tags: java, java-stream, instanceof

Suppose we have a Stream of Animals.

We have different Subclasses of Animals, and we want to apply a filter on the stream to only have the Zebras of the Stream. We now still have a Stream of Animals, but only containing Zebras. To get a stream of Zebras we still need to cast.

```java
Stream<Zebra> zebraStream = animalStream
    .filter(Zebra.class::isInstance)
    .map(Zebra.class::cast);
```

Java 14 introduced pattern matching for instanceof, so we can now use:

```java
if (animal instanceof Zebra zebra) {
    System.out.println(zebra.countStripes());
}
```

Is there a way to use pattern matching in stream pipes?
Of course you could do something like this:

```java
Stream<Zebra> zebraStream = animalStream.map(animal -> {
        if (animal instanceof Zebra zebra) {
            return zebra;
        }
        return null;
    })
    .filter(Objects::nonNull);
```

But IMHO this is really ugly.

Comment: "*Is there a way to use pattern matching in stream pipes?*" - As of yet, no. Filtering and mapping are distinct operations in streams. We cannot do both in one operation.

Comment: @Turing85 Yes, we can! See the first part of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74416358/17949945).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko nice. TIL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pattern matching + mapMulti

To coerce a Stream of supertype to a Stream of one of its subtypes, you can make use of the [*Pattern matching for instanceof*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394) in conjunction with Java 16 [`mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)), which expects a stream element and a `Consumer` of the resulting type:

```
Stream<Animal> animalStream = Stream.of();

Stream<Zebra> zebraStream = animalStream
    .mapMulti((animal, consumer) -> {
        if (animal instanceof Zebra zebra) consumer.accept(zebra);
    });
```

## Pattern matching + flatMap

To use Pattern matching for instanceof you can also employ a classic stream operation `flatMap()`, which is like `mapMulti()` is meant to perform *one-to-many* transformations.

The important distinction between the two is that `mapMulti()` replace the initial stream element with *zero or more* elements via its `Consumer`, meanwhile `flatMap()` require a producing a new Stream to flatten the data. And in this case utilizing `mapMulti()` would be more advantages because if the list is large generating singleton-streams for every element might be costful.

```
Stream<Zebra> zebraStream = animalStream
    .flatMap(animal -> 
        animal instanceof Zebra zebra ? Stream.of(zebra) : null
    );
```

**Note** that according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) instead of an empty stream, we can also return `null` (*which is handy because* `Stream.empty()` *doesn't return constant but spawns a new object*):

> If a mapped stream is `null` an empty stream is used, instead.

Comment: I still hope, that one day, streams are intelligent enough to do that automagically

Comment: Of special note, this exact use case of filtering + casting is one of the examples given in the [`mapMulti`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) Javadocs.